# How to specify resulting data type for arithmetic operations in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

It seems subtracting a float32 number from an int array results in a float64 array by default. Is there a way to circumvent this and get float32 as data type of the result instead?

[numpy.subtract](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) doesn't allow to specify a dtype argument.

The only way to achieve this for me was converting the int array to float32 before, effectively subtracting two float32 arrays which also seems to be rather slow. Is this the way it is supposed to be?

Example code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # some int32 array
    a = np.arange(1e7)
    print('a.dtype={}'.format(a.dtype)) # int32

    # subtraction with a python float
    t0 = time.clock()
    b = a - 5.5
    t1 = time.clock()
    print('b.dtype={}, took {}s'.format(b.dtype, t1 - t0)) # float64

    # a numpy float32
    c = np.array(5.5, dtype=np.float32)
    print('c.dtype={}'.format(c.dtype))  # float32

    # subtraction with the numpy float32
    t0 = time.clock()
    d = a - c
    t1 = time.clock()
    print('d.dtype={}, took {}s'.format(d.dtype, t1 - t0)) # float64! why not float32

    # convert the int32 to float32
    e = a.astype(dtype=np.float32)
    print('e.dtype={}'.format(e.dtype)) # float32

    # subtract two float32 array
    t0 = time.clock()
    e = a.astype(dtype=np.float32)
    f = e - c
    t1 = time.clock()
    print('f.dtype={}, took {}s'.format(f.dtype, t1 - t0)) # float32 (finally)
```

prints

```
a.dtype=float64
b.dtype=float64, took 0.0229595559008s
c.dtype=float32
d.dtype=float64, took 0.0223958136306s
e.dtype=float32
f.dtype=float32, took 0.0334388477586s
```

Converting manually to float32 before seems to be slower than automatically converting to float64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a ufunc, `np.subtract` accepts [several keyword arguments](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufunc) that aren't listed on its main doc page. One of these is dtype, so you can do, say: `np.subtract(a, b, dtype='float32')` and achieve the result you want.

In  case it's helpful in future, [`np.promote_types`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html)  will tell you the smallest dtype to which two dtypes both can be safely cast, and [`np.result_type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) will tell you the dtype Numpy's casting rules will yield by default.

Comment: Trying that was literally my first thought and I thought I had tried it first. But it seems I hadn't. Thanks also for promote_types and result_type.